# MySQL search different tables and only fetch specfic IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

I am trying to create an algorithm to sort out the most relevant data for a specific user_id.

I imagine my end result to be an array with KEY as the found USER_ID and the VALUE to be the number of times the specific USER_ID has been found in the different rows.

So, I need to look through different rows in different tables and look for where CURRENT_USER_ID (lets say id: 30) exists, and then find the RECIEVER_ID, that is the user which was communicated to. This is pretty hard to explain, but lets take an example:

- I have a table called: edu_posts, which contains wallposts and comments to theese. The are different values in this table, but the ones we should focus on is: post_author and post_reciever. We then have to look for all the rows where post_author equals 30 (the test example; just needs to be the current users id) and then print out the post_reciever IDS. This would be easy enough with a single query, but lets say we have to find data in 5 or 10 different tables, that 10 different queries, which is a lot.
- We also have a table called edu_folowers. There we have to look for where follow_author equals 30 (the test example; just needs to be the current users id), and then print out the follow_user ID. Again, to find out who the current user have interest in.

I image the final mysql_fetch to look something like this:

```
user_id => 25
times_found => 5
user_id => 11
times_found => 3
user_id => 95
times_found => 1
```

etc.

Can this be done using a single query, maybe using JOIN? And even maybe count the results IN the query, so I don't have to do this manually in the PHP code.

Or should I create a mysql_query for every table I wish to get data from, and then manage the data afterwards using PHP? This sounds like the easiest way to me, but also the most inefficient relating to script optimization.

I have tried out with the following test-query:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id AS user_id,
    f.follow_user AS user_id_follow,
    p.post_reciever AS user_id_posts
FROM
    `edu_posts` u
LEFT JOIN `edu_followers` f ON f.follow_author = '30'
LEFT JOIN `edu_posts` p ON p.post_author = '30' && p.post_reciever != '30'
WHERE 
    u.user_id = '30'
GROUP BY
    f.follow_id, p.post_id
```

But the problem is that it outputs unexcepted results, and also I will have different values to look for, fx: user_id (not really needed, as we already know that it is 30), user_id_follow, user_id_posts, and so on.

I hope you understand my question, and please let me know, if you need additional information.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: the join, needs ON statement to have column from one table to relate a column to another table. Columns, which are equal to a certain values, should be moved in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a union view of all of the tables that you want to search, depending on your exact requirements you might only need to query that once.

e.g.

```
create view allPostTypesUnion as
select user_id, post_receiver
from   edu_posts
union
select user_id, post_receiver
from   different_edu_posts
union
select user_id, post_receiver
from   another_different_edu_posts
```

then:

```
select post_receiver, count(*)
from   allPostTypes
group by post_receiver
```

Comment: OK. I read a bit about views, as I had no knowledge about that before. Interesting! However, I seems as the view groups by the content, at least, if I have 2 posts, which are created by the same user, and TO the same user, it is only listed once in the view.

Comment: `union` automatically includes a `distinct`. If you want to see duplicates, then use `union all`

Comment: Wow - the code makes sense. Then I guess I just union all the tables I want to collect data from, and it's also very easy to add new tables to the query, as more may be added. However, how often should I run this "create view" query? Every time the wall page is loaded? In a cronjob? Which is most suitable?

Comment: You only need to create a view once, but you would need to update the definition every time you wanted to add/remove tables or columns.

Comment: I assume you update the view by changing "CREATE VIEW" to "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW", right? But we could imagine users will be posting comments, likes, posts, etc, every second. Therefore the view has to bee updated so the algorithm is always UP-TO-DATE. I assume that I will just leave the CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW @ the wall page, right? Or that the view at least will be update every 30 mins, for instance.

Comment: Views will automatically stay consistently up to date with source data. When a row is added or removed to any table within the view, it will immediately appear or disappear from the view results. You don't need to do anything. The only time you would need to update the view definition is if you added or removed a column or table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37104/discussion-between-mattias-and-paul)